# Receiver has no segue with identifier "popUpSegue" (Swift 3)

Tags: ios, swift3, segue

I'm kinda new to swift and i'm having trouble implementing this segue between "ViewController" and "PopUpViewController." I'm trying to pass over an array of quotes between the view but keep getting the "Receiver has no segue with identifier 'popUpSegue' error."

I made absolutely sure that my segue's identifier was written correctly across my code and storyboard, i've done the "product --> clean" resolution proposed on another post, nothing has worked.

Something to note: I'm not performing this segue using a button, I had manually set it from the ViewController storyboard (ctrl-clicked the yellow button on the view controller). I'm not sure if that might have anything to with my issue.

[image: Segue Identifier picture]

[image: Segue setup picture]

ViewController.swift

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

// MARK: Properties

@IBOutlet weak var toucanTut: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var canTooLabel: UILabel!

let quoteArray: NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()





let tapRecon = UITapGestureRecognizer()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    tapRecon.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.tappedView))
    toucanTut.isUserInteractionEnabled = true;

    toucanTut.addGestureRecognizer(tapRecon)

    let urlPath: String = "https://web.njit.edu/~mid6/service.php"

    //Retrieves data from DB and handles it

    if let url = URL(string: urlPath){

        if let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url){
            let json = try? JSON(data: data)

            //print(json!)

            parse(json: json!)

        }
    }

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

//MARK: Actions

func tappedView(){
    let popOverVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "quotePopUp") as! PopUpViewController
    self.addChildViewController(popOverVC)
    popOverVC.view.frame = self.view.frame
    self.view.addSubview(popOverVC.view)
    popOverVC.didMove(toParentViewController: self)


}



func parse(json: JSON) {

    for(i , object) in json{

        let quote = object["quote"].stringValue
        let author = object["author"].stringValue

        //print(quote)

        let data = IncomingData()

        data.quote = quote
        data.author = author

        quoteArray.add(data)

        //print(data)
    }

    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "popUpSegue", sender: quoteArray)

}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "popUpSegue"
    {
        if let destinationVC = segue.destination as? PopUpViewController {
            destinationVC.newArray = sender as! NSMutableArray
        }
    }
}



}
```

PopUpViewController.swift

```
import UIKit

class PopUpViewController: UIViewController {

//Properties

var feedItems: NSArray = NSArray()
var selectedLocation : IncomingData = IncomingData()

var newArray: NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()

@IBOutlet weak var quoteText: UILabel!



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white.withAlphaComponent(0.8)

   checkQuotes()

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

//Actions

@IBAction func closePopUp(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    self.view.removeFromSuperview()

}

// check is quoteArray passed over

func checkQuotes(){

    print(newArray.count)


 }



}
```

Comment: You got this error because `ViewController` doesn't have a segue with identifier `popUpSegue`. But `PopUpViewController` has a segue with identifier `popUpSeque`. Select and delete the segue from the storyboard and create seque from `ViewController` to `PopUpViewController`

Comment: @RajeshkumarR wow totally missed that thanks! I'm not getting that error anymore, but the array I'm trying to pass through is still coming up empty in the second view- should I post a new question for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **sender**    The object that you want to use to initiate the segue.
>   This  object is made available for informational purposes during the
>   actual  segue.

Change these lines

```
self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "popUpSegue", sender: quoteArray)
destinationVC.newArray = sender as! NSMutableArray
```

To

```
self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "popUpSegue", sender: self)
destinationVC.newArray = quoteArray
```